# Cloudmade map api

Tags: google-maps, maps, geocoding, cloudmade

I am looking for a solution for cloudmade that will let me click a point on the map and set a radius for a circle. I was wanting to get the cleanest interface to do this. I looked on the cloudmade forums and the devs said that they have not put this into the API. I am looking for something like this [page](http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm). I would use google maps but we are using it for internal use and do not have the 10,000 dollars to pay for google map license.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to get the point and use MySQL lat long to do the calculations.